# How to count active users base using window functions?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a database `clients` with users' activities and I need to calculate the 30-day active users base. For any day 30-day active users base is a number of unique clients for the previous 30 days ago. For instance, for the 1st of Jan 30-day active users base is the number of clients for the previous 30 days including the 1st of Jan. For the 2nd of Jan this is the same including the 2nd of Jan and so on.

The structure of the database is the following:

```
cityname: character, the name of the city
date: datetime, the date
orderid: int, the id of the order
clientid: int, the id of the client
sales: float, the sum of sales in conventional units
```

So I need to calculate daily dynamics of 30-days active users base for each city from 2014-01-01 to 2014-06-30.

What I do is creating the CTE and then pulling the data using window function. But this approach is wrong as the last it does not count the number of users from the last day of a month with the number of users of the 1st day of the consecutive month.

```
WITH new_tbl as (
  SELECT cityname, date, COUNT(DISTINCT clientid) as client_ids
  FROM clients 
  GROUP BY cityname, date
)

SELECT cityname, date,
       SUM(client_ids) OVER(PARTITION BY cityname ORDER BY cityname, date) as active_base
FROM new_tbl
```

Really do struggle with this task but cannot find the right solution. Also tried something like this:

```
SELECT ...
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientid) OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... UNBOUNDED ... PRECEEDING ...) as active_base
FROM clients
```

But count + distinct do not work with window functions, so I get the error. What solution fits me better to get the desirable result?

```
cityname     date       active_base

 city1    2014-02-01        234
   …          …              …
 city1    2014-06-30        876
 city2    2014-02-01       1950
   …          …              …
 city2    2014-06-30       5910
```

Comment: An answer could be product-specific, so what DBMS you are using?

Comment: @Ahmed I am writing the query in sqlite

Comment: Are all of the dates *from 2014-01-01 to 2014-06-30* existed in the table, or maybe there are some dates where is no sales occur? in other words, does the sales occur daily? in this case we don't need to use a calendar table.

Comment: yes, there are sales for every date

Answer (score 0):

You may try a self join as the following:

```
select T.cityname, T.sdate, 
       COUNT(distinct D.clientid) active_base
from clients T join clients D
on T.sdate between D.sdate and date(D.sdate, '+29 day')
and T.cityname=D.cityname
where T.sdate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-06-30'
group by T.cityname, T.sdate
order by T.cityname, T.sdate
```

See a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vv8rCpAVfi9i77qXPHyr9J/1), the demo uses 3 days interval because of the small number of rows in the sample date.

Comment: yeah, I see, thank you. however, the query takes a very long time to process. that is why I specified in the title of question that i'd like to do that using window function

Comment: I just tried to help :)